# What parameter does it provide when we use "open with" on a file?

Tags: python, linux, image, file, bash

I have made an image viewer in python. And I want to use it to view images from my folders. I have made a bash file, which would start the image viewer. Now I am stuck. When I right click on an image, and choose option "open with" and provide bash file(above mentioned file, to start image viewer), what arguments/parameters (if any) does it pass to bash script ?
I am using Arch Linux. My Desktop environment is Gnome + Awesome. My File Manager is Nautilus.

I have stopped using bash file(which I have mentioned earlier in the question).

I have added

```
   #!/usr/bin/python2
```

and made it executable.
It's working in terminal.

I have added alias in .bashrc as

```
   alias imview='~/./image-viewer.py'
```

When used imview in terminal, it works.

But when I add imview you in "open with" command line, A new tab opens, but then it doesn't work. And it hides after few seconds.
Any idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: And which desktop environment? Btw., did you try just echoing the command line parameters from your script?

Comment: Yes. I tried using echo. But there was some problem. My file manager stopped working. I couldn't restart it. So I deleted the alias. and logged out. file manage is now working fine when I logged back in.

Comment: An alias won't do, it only works in interactive Bash scripts.

Comment: I am not using any bash scripts.
and you are saying that an alias won't work.
So should I just use ~/./inage-viewer.py ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a Bash script to start your image viewer. Instead add this as your first line in the Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And also make the Python script executable.

Then you will be able to run the script directly.

If you select "Open with..." then the filename should the be first argument to the script (`sys.argv[1]`).

Comment: I made it executable. It's working when I use it in terminal.
but it's not working when I use "open with". 
I am executing it in terminal and giving command line as ~/./image-viewer.py . What could be the problem ? My file is named image-viewer.py and is in home directory.
I also tried using bash script.
         ./image-viewer.py $1
A tab opens "Opening image" but then there's nothing.

Comment: Yeah. I got the problem with bash script. It only gives file name as argument. And so there was a problem. But I am still not able to use executable script. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to a shell script are available as `"$1"`, `"$2"`, etc. The variable `"$@"` contains the entire list of arguments, and the value of `$#` indicates how many arguments there are.

It is unclear why you need a shell script, though. In the trivial case, add a shebang line to your Python script (something like `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of the script file) and mark it executable.